# Hot to make a PATCH request to Firebase REST API using python (urllib2)?

Tags: python, firebase

I am trying to update Firebase entity using [PATCH](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/). Here is what I have:

Data:

```
'foo': {
  'bar': 'baz'
}
```

Rules:

```
"foo": {
      ".write": true,
      ".read": true,
      "bar": {
        ".write": true,
        ".read": true,
      }
},
```

Code:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

AUTH_SECRET = 'redacted'
BASE_URL = 'redacted'
URL = BASE_URL + '/foo/.json'

values = {'bar' : 'baz3'}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)

request = urllib2.Request(URL + '?auth=' + AUTH_SECRET, data)
request.get_method = lambda: 'PATCH'
resp = urllib2.urlopen(request)

print resp.read()
```

I am getting "HTTP Error 400: Bad Request".

Comment: Why am I being down-voted?

Comment: Are you tried escape your string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the code for sending requests in `try/except` and then read what is sent back as a content in case of an error, like this:

```
from urllib2 import HTTPError
try:
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(request)
except HTTPError as e:
    print e.read()
```

I ran your code and that's what I received:

```
{
  "error" : "Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object. Are you sending a JSON object with valid key names?"
}
```

So Firebase expects you to send data in JSON while you sending it like a URL query string `'bar=baz3'`. Thus serializing the data into a JSON formated string would fix the error:

```
import json
values = {'bar': 'baz3'}
data = json.dumps(values)
```

---

Also I would recommend you to use [Requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/master/) library, since it's much nicer to use.

First of all install Requests:

```
pip install requests
```

And then you could do it like this:

```
import urllib
import requests


AUTH_SECRET = 'redacted'
BASE_URL = 'redacted'

get_params = urllib.urlencode({'auth': AUTH_SECRET})
url = BASE_URL + '/foo/.json' + '?' + get_params
data = {'bar': 'baz3'}

resp = requests.patch(url, json=data)
print resp.json()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use urllib  to build the URL with the params? You can just give them as dict to requests.